# Splitting Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I have been trying to split an array into two groups currently my array looks like this.

```
Array
(
    [cities] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 0
                    [storename] => test
                    [notes] => test
                    [rejected] => off
                    [offer] => 
                    [time] => 1393585744241
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [storename] => test2
                    [notes] => test2
                    [rejected] => on
                    [offer] => test2
                    [time] => 1393585751264
                )

        )
```

)

**PHP**

```
foreach( $array['cities'] as $data)
{
    if($data['rejected'] == "off"){

        $rejected = array();

        array_push($rejected, $data['id'], $data['storename'], $data['offer']);


    }

    if($data['rejected'] == "on"){

        $nonerejected = array();

        array_push($nonerejected, $data['id'], $data['storename'], $data['offer']);


    }


}
```

Any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$nonerejected = array();
$rejected = array();
foreach( $array['cities'] as $data)
{
    if($data['rejected'] == "off"){
        array_push($rejected, $data['id'], $data['storename'], $data['offer']);
    }

    if($data['rejected'] == "on"){
        array_push($nonerejected, $data['id'], $data['storename'], $data['offer']);
    }
}
```

You should declare the `$nonerejected` and `$rejected` array outside `foreach` loop

Answer (score 2):

You are repeatedly re-creating the arrays. Move `$rejected = array()` and `$nonrejected = array()` to be *before* the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yo are creating the arrays on each iteration into the `foreach` loop. You must create the `$rejected` and the `$nonerejected` outside the loop, before it:

```
$nonerejected = array();
$rejected = array();
foreach( $array['cities'] as $data)
{
    if($data['rejected'] == "off"){        

        array_push($rejected, $data['id'], $data['storename'], $data['offer']);
    }

    if($data['rejected'] == "on"){        

        array_push($nonerejected, $data['id'], $data['storename'], $data['offer']);
    }
}
```